# IPv6 connection with Android4.x to MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, ipv6

I'm trying to connect my Android 4.x Emulator to a MySQL database stored in my computer. I can connect to it without problems with Android 2.x which uses IPv4 but I can't with 3.X or 4.X because uses IPv6.

I have installed MySQL 5.6 and I'm trying this code to connect.

```
private static Connection conexionMySQL = null;

public static void CreaConexion (Context context, String usuario, String pass, String ip, String puerto, String catalogo)
{       
    if (conexionMySQL == null)      
    {
        String urlConexionMySQL = "";

        if (catalogo != "")
        {
            urlConexionMySQL = "jdbc:mysql://address=(protocol=tcp)(host="+ip+")(port="+puerto+")(user=root)/"+catalogo+"";
        }
        else
            urlConexionMySQL = "jdbc:mysql://address=(protocol=tcp)(host="+ip+")(port="+puerto+")(user=root)/";

        if (usuario != "" & pass != "" & ip != "" & puerto != "")
        {
            try 
            {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                Toast.makeText(context, urlConexionMySQL, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                conexionMySQL = DriverManager.getConnection(urlConexionMySQL, usuario, pass);
            } 
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
            {
                  Toast.makeText(context, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } 
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                  Toast.makeText(context, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this on my 'my.cnf' file:

```
# SERVER SECTION
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# The following options will be read by the MySQL Server. Make sure that
# you have installed the server correctly (see above) so it reads this 
# file.
#
# server_type=3
[mysqld]

# The next three options are mutually exclusive to SERVER_PORT below.
# skip-networking
# enable-named-pipe
# The Pipe the MySQL Server will use
# socket=mysql

# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
port=3306
bind-address=*
```

I'm getting all the time the error: Communications link failure, last packet sent succesfully was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

i don't know what to do right now, help!!!

Editted:

I'm using this at the CMD:
    shell> mysql -h ::1

and it works so my DB is configured to get IPv6 connections, but the problem keeps the same, I can connect with 2.x version but I can't with higher ones.

Comment: Why do you think this has anything to do with IPv6? This question is woefully incomplete...

Comment: The only difference I've saw between the connection with Android2.x and Android4.x is the IPversion of each client. In 2.x it works without problems but in 4.x I can't connect.

Tell me what do you need of my code and I'll add to the question.